# Firebase for a "big" amount of data

Tags: angular, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, nosql

We are planning migrating our application to Firebase for realtime capabilities and to improve performance.
It`s a sales application which stores costumers products and sales data.
Our costumers (we call it Groups) have in general 10 stores each (we call it Companies).

It`s not a big deal to handle this amount of data.
But recently we made a deal with a big Group which has 1.000+ stores (and 20 new ones every month).

My question is how to structure this data without having performance issues and keep the realtime features?

I think if we focus on how to structure Groups-Companies we can handle the other parts (sales, products, etc)

```
"Groups": {
    "Group1": {
      "name": "Historical Tech Pioneers"
    },
    "Group2": { ... }
}

"Stores": {
    "Store1": {
      "name": "abc",
      "group" "Group1"
    },
    "Store2": {
      "name": "def",
      "group" "Group1"
    },
}
```

Is this data structure ok to deal with thousands of records every time?

I am very concern about Firebase performance if every time I have to query for over 1.000 stores.
Everybody says that 1.000 records is nothing for Firebase, but I did some tests and found that retrieving 1.000 records is not as fluid as they say.

Comment: You want a query to retrieve all 1000 records to some client app?  That doesn't sounds like a good idea.  Typically you want to use an index query by some value in those records to retrieve just one or a small subset of them.

Comment: [https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/web/structure-data](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/web/structure-data)

Comment: Actually, not all Users will access all Stores. I think a good idea will be a User_Stores node where I can store all Stores a user has access to.

Comment: @HugoRamos "I did some tests and found that retrieving 1.000 records is not as fluid as they say" Please show the code for your test. Better yet: reproduce it in a place where we can access it, such as a jsbin. Only then can we all look at the same thing and help you optimize. Also see my explanation of list size limits here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39712833/firebase-performance-how-many-children-per-node/39713060#39713060

Comment: Discussing NoSQL data models is only meaningful in the context of a specific use-case. You'll often expand your data model to cater for new use-cases. For a general introduction see [NoSQL data modeling](https://highlyscalable.wordpress.com/2012/03/01/nosql-data-modeling-techniques/) and view [Firebase for SQL developers](https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLl-K7zZEsYLlP-k-RKFa7RyNPa9_wCH2s).

Answer (score 0):

So i have na **suggestion** that is to **organize** the firebase data like that for exemple:

```
"Groups": {
    "Group1": {
        "name": "Historical Tech Pioneers"
        "Stores": {
            "Store1": {
                "name": "abc"
            },          
            "Store2": {
                "name": "def"
            }
        },
    },
    "Group2": { ... }
}
```

And to get the store just poit to Groups>Group1>Stores. For better performance add pages to firebase data, for exemple 10 stores per page.

**Note:** is only a suggestion.

Comment: If one would want to fetch a list of all group names, it means you would get all of the groups stores. Thats a lot of unnecessary data being sent...

Comment: Yeah you are right i dont think in that possibility i only think in the performance to get all stores, my bad.

Answer (score 0):

Since fetching data at a location in your database also retrieves all of its child nodes, you want to keep the database structure as flat as possible. Your suggestion resembles the structure in the [docs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/web/structure-data). Which to me seems your on the right track.

Looking at your example i would probably re-structure the `Stores`-node, to easily get all Stores of a group:

```
"Stores": {
    "Group1": {
        "Store1": {
            "name": "abc"
        },
        "Store2": {
            "name": "def"
        },
        ...
    },
    ...        
}
```

In the documentation (one [example](https://howtofirebase.com/firebase-data-modeling-939585ade7f4)) i have read denormalization is a keyword. Don't be afraid to duplicate data in order to speed up your reads. How you intend to use your data should determine how you structure your data.

As Chris Esplin [wrote](https://howtofirebase.com/firebase-data-modeling-939585ade7f4):
'We have to constantly balance normalization (shallow structures) vs denormalization (deep structure) based on how we want to use our data.'

Comment: Good to know we are doing it right. But the question remains: At client side, eventually, 1.000 records will be heavy to handle?

Comment: Firebase is designed to handle large datasets. How do you handle the datasets client side? What event do you use to retrieve data? `value` `child_added`?

Comment: I handle datasets on client side. I think one of the goals of using Firebase as BaaS is to handle data without the need of a custom API. Am I right?