# Firebase Pagination: How to perform optimum pagination?

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, pagination

I have a firebase structure that looks like this:

```
<root>
 |-my-app-name
   |-post
     |-<uid1>
       |-negatedtimestamp
       |-sub nodes
       |-...
     |-<uid2>
       |-negatedtimestamp
       |-sub nodes
       |-...
```

I have my pagination done by `limitToFirst(10)` and `orderbyChild("negatedtimestamp")` to retrieve the recent 10 items. The last uid is saved, and was queried again at loadmore() with `startAt(<uid>)`.

In term of scalability, when the node post grow to ten or hundred of thousands, query the first/last 10 will leads to slower time as it is asking the database to consider all of the nodes. There is a solution for this by storing only the keys of recent 10 items in another nodes, retrieve them, and read directly from the parent node. This was suggested at here:https://stackoverflow.com/a/39713060/9088278

However, in order to perform pagination, the recent 10 node is changing when `loadmore()` function is hit as it needs to load the older 10, then older 10 again. How can I do pagination by this way? Or is there any alternative?