# Firebase Realtime Database consuming CPU / memory with excessive "userWrites"

Tags: ios, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I'm using the Firebase Realtime Database on an iOS project. I've had a growing number of reports from users about my app consuming lots of battery, and have recently done a bit of profiling. On my device the app is using 100% CPU and more than 0.5 Gb memory (and growing) for minutes at a time - the Time Profiler suggests its Firebase that's the culprit, with more than 8.77 minutes out of 10.09 minutes spent in the `[FRepo restoreWrites]` method (3.22 minutes in `[FCompoundWrite addWrite:atPath:]`). This is with persistence enabled.

I dug in to the code for `restoreWrites` and it seems that its performance is related to the number of `userWrites` records. `[[[[[[reference repo] persistenceManager] storageEngine] writesDB] allKeys] count]` comes out at about 75,000 (and growing every time I launch the app) - is this how many writes have been persisted to disk that haven't yet been written to the server? Or is this the total number of records across all users? I don't know. But either way it's constantly growing and causing massive performance issues.

Is this inevitable and a reason to migrate to FireStore? Or is this something wrong I'm doing that is fixable?

Here's the full profile info to show you what I'm talking about:

```
9.41 min   93.2%    0 s      _dispatch_workloop_worker_thread$VARIANT$mp  0x109890
9.41 min   93.2%    0 s       _pthread_wqthread
9.41 min   93.2%    0 s        _dispatch_workloop_worker_thread$VARIANT$mp
9.41 min   93.2%    0 s         _dispatch_root_queue_drain_deferred_wlh$VARIANT$mp
9.41 min   93.2%    0 s          _dispatch_queue_invoke$VARIANT$mp
9.37 min   92.9%    0 s           _dispatch_queue_serial_drain$VARIANT$mp
9.37 min   92.9%    0 s            _dispatch_client_callout
9.37 min   92.9%    0 s             _dispatch_call_block_and_release
8.78 min   87.0%    0 s              -[FRepo deferredInit]
8.77 min   87.0%    0 s               -[FRepo restoreWrites]
7.30 min   72.3%    0 s                -[__NSArrayM enumerateObjectsWithOptions:usingBlock:]
6.55 min   64.9%    1.00 ms                 __22-[FRepo restoreWrites]_block_invoke
5.69 min   56.3%    4.00 ms                  -[FSyncTree applyUserMergeAtPath:changedChildren:writeId:]
5.67 min   56.2%    8.00 ms                   -[FWriteTree addMergeAtPath:changedChildren:writeId:]
5.63 min   55.8%    5.00 ms                    -[FCompoundWrite addCompoundWrite:atPath:]
5.63 min   55.8%    0 s                     -[FImmutableTree forEach:]
5.63 min   55.8%    1.00 ms                      -[FImmutableTree forEachPathSoFar:withBlock:]
3.43 min   34.0%    1.00 ms                       -[FArraySortedDictionary enumerateKeysAndObjectsReverse:usingBlock:]
3.42 min   33.9%    3.00 ms                        __45-[FImmutableTree forEachPathSoFar:withBlock:]_block_invoke
3.32 min   32.9%    7.00 ms                         -[FImmutableTree forEachPathSoFar:withBlock:]
3.31 min   32.8%    6.00 ms                          __42-[FCompoundWrite addCompoundWrite:atPath:]_block_invoke
3.22 min   31.9%    9.00 ms                           -[FCompoundWrite addWrite:atPath:]
```

Comment: Roughly how much data are you persisting to disk? Also: how many pending writes (so local writes that happened while there is no network connection) are there? Those two combined are what the client needs to process when the app restarts. For a good discussion on the topic, see https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/firebase-talk/G50gHcoSZ30 (and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36401332/firebase-android-offline-performance, although I'm not sure of the solution offered there).

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen on iOS is there an easy way to find out the number of pending writes?

Comment: I don't think there's a public API to get such a count on any platform. Sorry about that.

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen Would the performance be any better with FireStore for the same answers to those two questions?

Comment: Also, is there even a "private" API I could use to give insight? e.g., as I say, I did [[[[[[reference repo] persistenceManager] storageEngine] writesDB] allKeys] count] and it came out at 75,000+ and growing

Comment: Sorry Andy, I don't know a lot about the internals of the iOS SDK. But a quick peek at the [code](https://github.com/firebase/firebase-ios-sdk/blob/f08b5044d64197a3227017ad44235a2bd7421691/Firebase/Database/Persistence/FLevelDBStorageEngine.m) seems to suggest that indeed `writesDB` may contain the pending writes. 75K is indeed quite a lot of writes to have to reconcile upon app startup.